# Line number of individual XML element while unmarshalling using jaxb

Tags: jaxb, jaxb2

I have a class Person with attributes name and address. I display it in a XML. While unmarshalling from XML will it be possible to get line number for name and address separately.
I tried using Locator. But it does not provide individual line numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) and the JAXB reference implementation each have their own `@XmlLocation` annotations for supporting this use case.  This allows you to store the location on the XML element corresponding to the object as an instance of `org.xml.sax.Locator`.  Since I'm the MOXy lead, I will demonstrate using MOXy:

**Person**

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlLocation;
import org.xml.sax.Locator;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Person {

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=StringAdapter.class)
    String name;

    Address address;

    @XmlLocation
    Locator locator;

}
```

**Address**

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlLocation;
import org.xml.sax.Locator;

public class Address {

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=StringAdapter.class)
    private String street;

    @XmlLocation
    Locator locator;

}
```

**StringAdapter**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlLocation;
import org.xml.sax.Locator;

public class StringAdapter extends XmlAdapter<StringAdapter.AdaptedString, String> {

    public static class AdaptedString {

        @XmlValue
        public String value;

        @XmlLocation
        @XmlTransient
        Locator locator;

    }

    @Override
    public String unmarshal(AdaptedString v) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(v.value + " " + v.locator.getLineNumber());
        return v.value;
    }

    @Override
    public AdaptedString marshal(String v) throws Exception {
        AdaptedString adaptedString = new AdaptedString();
        adaptedString.value = v;
        return adaptedString;
    }

}
```

**jaxb.properties**

To specify MOXy as your JAXB provider you need to include a file called `jaxb.properties` in the same package as your domain model with the following entry.

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

**Demo**

```java
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Person.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum14455596/input.xml");
        Person person = (Person) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        System.out.println("Person:  " + person.locator.getLineNumber());
        System.out.println("Address:  " + person.address.locator.getLineNumber());
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
Jane Doe 3
1 A Street 5
Person:  2
Address:  4
```

Comment: In the above example, will it be possible to get the line number for Street which is a String value in XML file

Comment: @AnandB - Where do you want to store the line number for `Street`?  Also out of curiosity why do you want to store all the line numbers?

Comment: @AnandB - I have updated my answer with an `XmlAdapter` approach that may work.  Ultimately you may not want to use `String` properties and just use a class like `AdaptedString` directly in your model.

Comment: @AnandB - It has now been added.

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan: Is there a way to have the classes auto-generated from schema?

Answer (score 2):

You could leverage a StAX `StreamReaderDelegate` and do something like the following:

**Demo**

```java
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.stream.*;
import javax.xml.stream.util.StreamReaderDelegate;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Person.class);

        XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
        StreamSource source = new StreamSource("src/forum14455596/input.xml");
        XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(source);
        xsr = new StreamReaderDelegate(xsr) {

            @Override
            public String getLocalName() {
                String localName = super.getLocalName();
                if(isStartElement()) {
                    System.out.println(localName + " " + this.getLocation().getLineNumber());
                }
                return localName;
            }

        };

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr);
    }

}
```

**Person**

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private String address;

}
```

**input.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<person>
    <name>Jane Doe</name>
    <address>1 A Street</address>
</person>
```

**Output**

```
person 2
name 3
address 4
```

Comment: How will I be able to achieve the same in case of nested XML files. Will it be possible to have a property like Locator inside individual classes.

Comment: @AnandB - That code will output the line number for each start element regardless of how deep the XML is.

Comment: Will it be possible to have a property like Locator inside individual classes.

Comment: @AnandB - You just want to store the location for each domain object?

Comment: @AnandB - I have added another answer demonstrating how to do this with the `@XmlLocation` extension.