# Line number of xinclude while unmarshalling using jaxb

Tags: java, jaxb, numbers, line, xinclude

I found this question on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455596/line-number-of-individual-xml-element-while-unmarshalling-using-jaxb). I shows how to get the line numbers of individual xml elements while unmarshalling with JAXB. I extended this example being able to use `xinclude`. Unfortunately, I'm not able to get the line number of the `xinclude`.

So, how do I get the line number of the actual `xinclude` statement? Here is the extended example:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.sax.SAXSource;

import org.xml.sax.EntityResolver;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException, SAXException,
            ParserConfigurationException, FileNotFoundException {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Person.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        spf.setXIncludeAware(true);
        spf.setNamespaceAware(true);
        spf.setValidating(true);

        File file = new File("src/person.xml");
        XMLReader xr = spf.newSAXParser().getXMLReader();
        xr.setEntityResolver(new EntityResolver() {
            @Override
            public InputSource resolveEntity(String publicId, String systemId)
                    throws SAXException, IOException {
                System.out.println(publicId + " -> " + systemId);
                return null;
            }
        });
        SAXSource source = new SAXSource(xr, new InputSource(
                new FileInputStream(file)));
        Person person = (Person) unmarshaller.unmarshal(source);

        System.out.println("Person:  " + person.locator.getLineNumber());
        System.out.println("Address:  "
                + person.address.locator.getLineNumber());
    }
}
```

The `EntityResolver` listener tells me that there is an `xinclude` statement, but I don't know on which line number.

**person.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<person xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
    <name>Jane Doe</name>
    <xi:include href="./src/address.xml" />
</person>
```

**address.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<address>1 A Street</address>
```

I didn't mention the `Person` and `Address` class, so this questions stays short and compact :) I also marked every `Locator` field with `@XmlTransient`. Thank you!